# Implementing a binary tree set

Tags: haskell, set, binary-tree

```hs
data Set a = Node | Tree (Set a) (Set a)
```

How can I implement a partition function which partitions the set into two sets, with all elements that satisfy the predicate on the left and the rest on the right as simply as possible?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you *insert* elements in your `Set`, and *enumerate* the elements.

Comment: Your type can't actually store any values of type `a`; it just stores some number of `Node` values. The definition should at least be `data Set a = Node a | Tree (Set a) (Set a)` or `data Set a = Node | Tree a (Set a) (Set a)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to represent Set as Tree in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44458721/is-it-possible-to-represent-set-as-tree-in-haskell)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, your type won't quite cut it.  A reasonable implementation of a set as a tree might have type:

```
data Set a = Leaf | Node a (Set a) (Set a) deriving (Show)
                         ^- note this extra `a`
```

where each internal `Node x l r` has all elements in `l` less than `x` and all elements in `r` greater than `x`.

You can partition such a `Set` recursively as follows:

```
partition :: (a -> Bool) -> Set a -> (Set a, Set a)
```

The `Leaf` case is easy, obviously:

```
partition _ Leaf = (Leaf, Leaf)
```

Here's how we do the `Node` case.  For the sub-case where the predicate holds for the value `x` in the node, note that we want:

```
partition f (Node x l r) | f x = (Node x l1 r1, ...)
```

where `l1` and `r1` are the subsets of elements in `l` and `r` that satisfy the predicate, which we can get by recursively partitioning `l` and `r`.

```
  where (l1, l2) = partition f l
        (r1, r2) = partition f r
```

The `Set` invariant will be preserved here, because all elements in `l`, including those in the subset `l1` are less than `x`; for the same reason, all elements in `r1` are greater than `x`.  The only missing piece is that we somehow need to combine `l2` and `r2` to form the second part of the tuple:

```
partition f (Node x l r) | f x = (Node x l1 r1, combine l2 r2)
```

Since `combine` is a function that takes two trees with all elements in the first tree less than all elements in the second tree, the following recursive function will do:

```
combine Leaf r' = r'
combine (Node x l r) r' = Node x l (combine r r')
```

The case where the predicate does *not* hold for `x` is handled similarly, giving the full definition:

```
data Set a = Leaf | Node a (Set a) (Set a)

partition :: (a -> Bool) -> Set a -> (Set a, Set a)
partition _ Leaf = (Leaf, Leaf)
partition f (Node x l r)
  | f x       = (Node x l1 r1, combine l2 r2)
  | otherwise = (combine l1 r1, Node x l2 r2)
  where (l1, l2) = partition f l
        (r1, r2) = partition f r

        combine Leaf r' = r'
        combine (Node x l r) r' = Node x l (combine r r')
```

Here's the complete code plus a QuickCheck test that that partition function works as expected:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import qualified Data.List (nub, partition, sort)
import Data.List (nub, sort)

data Set a = Leaf | Node a (Set a) (Set a) deriving (Show)

partition :: (a -> Bool) -> Set a -> (Set a, Set a)
partition _ Leaf = (Leaf, Leaf)
partition f (Node x l r)
  | f x       = (Node x l1 r1, combine l2 r2)
  | otherwise = (combine l1 r1, Node x l2 r2)
  where (l1, l2) = partition f l
        (r1, r2) = partition f r

        combine Leaf r' = r'
        combine (Node x l r) r' = Node x l (combine r r')

insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Set a -> Set a
insert x Leaf = Node x Leaf Leaf
insert x (Node y l r) = case compare x y of
  LT -> Node y (insert x l) r
  GT -> Node y l (insert x r)
  EQ -> Node y l r

fromList :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Set a
fromList = foldr insert Leaf

toList :: (Ord a) => Set a -> [a]
toList Leaf = []
toList (Node x l r) = toList l ++ x : toList r

prop_partition :: [Int] -> Bool
prop_partition lst =
  let (l, r) = Main.partition even (fromList lst') in (toList l, toList r)
  == Data.List.partition even (sort $ lst')
  where lst' = nub lst

main = quickCheck (withMaxSuccess 10000 prop_partition)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so thoroughly!